# On "Random Walk: Drunk Man in a Cliff" Problem, Why $qP$ in the equation $P = p + qP^2$?

Tags: probability, random-walk

There are several solution presented in this "drunk man at the edge of the cliff" problem.

1. [Random Walk of a drunk man](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716418/random-walk-of-a-drunk-man)
2. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/does-the-drunk-man-fall-off-the-cliff-a-random-walk-problem

One approach caught my attention, it is straightforward but I don't fully understand it.  It is required to find for *P* where *q* and *p* are given and this is the equation:

$P = p + qP^2$

I have two questions:

1. Why is it that the probability of moving to the right is *qP*? I understand why the probability of moving to the left after it is (*qP*)*P*.
2. I am more a visual learner, I can easily comprehend and easily explain in drawing.  Here is how I interpreted it.

[image]

I am not sure though if I interpreted it right.  Thank you in advance for shading some light.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment of @cato, I come up with this figure.

[image]

I think this is the right one.

Comment: Have you got typos? Do you mean $P=p+qP^2$?

Comment: p is the chance he steps right off the cliff on his first step, so P = p is a lower bound  - if he steps right with probability q, then there is again a  probability P that he will return to the original starting point, at which time his chance of death will again be P - so $P = p + qP^2$ seems to make sense - if he never returns to 1, then there is no chance of reaching 0, so we don't need to consider that any further

Comment: he either falls straight off, or goes right, if he goes right then can you see why P is the chance he ends up back at 'start' at any time?  if he ever does end up at 'start' then there is again an absolute probability of P that he ever falls off (due to the memoryless property of the problem) - at the outset, his chances of dying are P = P(goes left) + P(goes right) x P(returns to start) x P

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes I made a typo. The post was has been updated.

Comment: @Cato can you shed some light if my diagram is right or wrong? How I understand your comment "P = P(goes left) + P(goes right) x P(returns to start) x P" sounds to me it is only one step each not x steps and (x + 1) steps.

Comment: @Cato is right and the solution to the problem you post as your 1 is right, and both seem to me to be quite clear. Why are you worried by $qP$? The term $qP^2$ arises as the product of $q$ (not falling off at the first step) times $P$ (the probability of ever returning from $2$ to the start) times $P$ (the probaiity of falling off once you've returned to the start).

Comment: I was worried by $qP$ after I check some numerical value.  Example if $q = 1/3$ and $p = 2/3$ I've got $P = 1/2$.

Comment: I think I mess up in my checking, As I wrote my previous comment, I remember that $P = 1/2$ applies to infinite number of steps.  I used it though to check for specific number of steps say, the probability of falling off the cliff in 5 steps which is $P(5) = 2(1/3)^3(2/3)^2$.

Comment: I already understand the $qP$.  I am now waiting for a response or a comment for my diagram.

Comment: I never quite understand the arguments that 1 cannot be a solution where p < q- why does it exist as a solution to the equation that emerges?  If it is in fact wrong, then what exactly does it mean?  All deeply troubling.  The explanations given always seem wordy and non-rigorous.