# Find probability function of random walk, stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

My question is how can I create my own probability functions ?

For example , take a look at this article at [medium](https://medium.com/i-math/the-drunkards-walk-explained-48a0205d304). At some point it produces

$$ P1 = (1 - q) + (qP1^2) $$

Which is the probability if a drunk man will fall from a cliff.

How the writer reaches to the conclusion that has to multiply q with $P1^2$  ?

Are there any resources(books, papers) that teaches (or have examples) someone how to produce this functions-this kind of solutions ?

I want to understand this problems and solutions but I cant find something relevant on the web.
Thanks

**Answer to my first question**

[On "Random Walk: Drunk Man in a Cliff" Problem, Why $qP$ in the equation $P = p + qP^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201158/on-random-walk-drunk-man-in-a-cliff-problem-why-qp-in-the-equation-p-p?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I was expecting this to get compiled in Latex I ll fix asap